# Adding artificial breakpoints

Tags: r, breakpoints

I have the following time series:

```
Lines <- "Hour,PF
0,14/01/2015 00:00,0.305
1,14/01/2015 01:00,0.306
2,14/01/2015 02:00,0.307
3,14/01/2015 03:00,0.3081
4,14/01/2015 04:00,0.3091
5,14/01/2015 05:00,0.3101
6,14/01/2015 06:00,0.3111
7,14/01/2015 07:00,0.3122
8,14/01/2015 08:00,0.455
9,14/01/2015 09:00,0.7103
10,14/01/2015 10:00,0.9656
11,14/01/2015 11:00,1
12,14/01/2015 12:00,0.9738
13,14/01/2015 13:00,0.9476
14,14/01/2015 14:00,0.9213
15,14/01/2015 15:00,0.8951
16,14/01/2015 16:00,0.8689
17,14/01/2015 17:00,0.8427
18,14/01/2015 18:00,0.6956
19,14/01/2015 19:00,0.6006
20,14/01/2015 20:00,0.5056
21,14/01/2015 21:00,0.4106
22,14/01/2015 22:00,0.3157
23,14/01/2015 23:00,0.3157"

library (zoo)
library (strucchange)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")

bp <- breakpoints(z ~ 1, h = 2)

plot(z)
abline(v = time(z)[bp$breakpoints])

The Breakpoints are at observation number:
8 10 18 21
```

Now suppose I have the same time series but at observation number 11 - 24 hours are missing. I would like to define `Gap` (=24 hours in this case) and  find the relevant breakpoints as in the previous example with 2 additional breakpoints at the beginning of the gap and  at the end. For the following time series the breakpoints will be:

```
8 10  12   13  18 21
```

Here is the time series with gaps:

```
 Lines <- "Hour,PF
    0,14/01/2015 00:00,0.305
    1,14/01/2015 01:00,0.306
    2,14/01/2015 02:00,0.307
    3,14/01/2015 03:00,0.3081
    4,14/01/2015 04:00,0.3091
    5,14/01/2015 05:00,0.3101
    6,14/01/2015 06:00,0.3111
    7,14/01/2015 07:00,0.3122
    8,14/01/2015 08:00,0.455
    9,14/01/2015 09:00,0.7103
    10,14/01/2015 10:00,0.9656 
    11,14/01/2015 11:00,1           <---
    12,15/01/2015 12:00,0.9738      <--- GAP of 24 hours
    13,15/01/2015 13:00,0.9476
    14,15/01/2015 14:00,0.9213
    15,15/01/2015 15:00,0.8951
    16,15/01/2015 16:00,0.8689
    17,15/01/2015 17:00,0.8427
    18,15/01/2015 18:00,0.6956
    19,15/01/2015 19:00,0.6006
    20,15/01/2015 20:00,0.5056
    21,15/01/2015 21:00,0.4106
    22,15/01/2015 22:00,0.3157
    23,15/01/2015 23:00,0.3157"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gap is actually a whole month (14/01 to14/02).

```
c(0,1)+which.max(diff(time(z))) # 12,13
```

will return the indices for the largest gap which you can append to your break points.

Note: the start and end of the gap is 12,13 not 11,12 since index in R starts from 1.

Comment: Thanks @fishtank, this gap is only an example there might be some more gaps larger or smaller. I would like to get the breakpoints for each gap and then I would like to find a fit (linear regression) for each segment and skip over the gaps. Finding the max difference won't be the solution.

Comment: I don't think `breakpoint` is meant to be used to identify "gaps". So the point of this example is that you can use `diff(time(z))` to find and evaluate (based on some criteria e.g. exceed 24h) what you consider "gaps".

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to add the ablines for the gaps (at the beginging and at the end) Is there a way to do it? I use abline(v = time(z)[which.max(diff(time(z)))]) but I don't want to use the which.max? How can I do it?

Comment: If I use abline(v = time(z)[c(0,1)+which.max(diff(time(z)))]) I get at the at the beginning and at the end but I don't want to use which.max since I might have some more gaps.

Comment: I used the folllowing: c<-diff(time(z))
abline(v = time(z) [c(0,1) + which (c>24)]) and it works!

Comment: Great! This is better: `abline(v=time(z)[c(which(c>24),which(c>24)+1)])` since you might have multiple "gaps" (so you might end up with `c(0,1) + c(11,25,60)` which would fail).